# menu_class causing a div having the class name in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a script

```
<?php 
           $menu=array(
               'theme_location'=> 'primary',
               'menu'=> '',
               'container'        => false,
               'container_class'  => '',
               'container_id'     => '',
               'menu_class'       => 'nav sf-menu',
               'menu_id'          => '',
               'echo'             => true,
               'fallback_cb'      => 'wp_page_menu',
               'before'           => '',
               'after'            => '',
               'link_before'      => '',
               'link_after'       => '',
               'items_wrap'       => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
               'depth'            => 0,
               'walker'           =>''
           )
      ;
      wp_nav_menu($menu);?>
```

It's intended to show a menu with `ul class="nav sf menu"` But the problem is that when I view source the page, I see this script:

```
<div class="nav sf-menu">
<ul>
<li class="current_page_item"><
a href="http://localhost/model.com/" title="Home">Home</a>
</li>
<li class="page_item page-item-2">
<a href="http://localhost/model.com/?page_id=2">Sample Page</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

How is that extra div coming on?

Answer (score 1):

Since there's no menu ID specified, it's falling back to call `wp_page_menu()`, which wraps with a div (ignoring your `container=>false` param).

Don't think there's a parameter to strip the div from wp_page_menu, but you can specify a different fallback (or just add a menu to your theme):

```
fallback_cb => 'wp_list_pages'
```

perhaps.